# Mailchimp API is giving HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I have  a script which is attempting to pull the Lists from Mailchimp.  The URL that is giving this list is:

```
https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=php&method=lists&apikey=XXXXXHIDDENKEYXXXXX-us8
```

By directly visiting the link, the serialized array of lists is displayed.  The issues is when I am using PHP to pull this information:

```
    $response = "";
    fwrite($sock, $payload);
    stream_set_timeout($sock, $this->timeout);
    $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    while ((!feof($sock)) && (!$info["timed_out"])) {
        $response .= fread($sock, $this->chunkSize);
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    }
    fclose($sock);
    ob_end_clean();
```

Once I print the `$response` variable, I get the following output:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=php&method=lists&apikey=XXXXXHIDDENKEYXXXXX-us8
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2018 16:33:55 GMT
Connection: close
```

Here is a link to the MCAPI library that I am using to get attempt the connection:

```
https://github.com/jbrooksuk/MCAPI-PHP
```

Why would this information be available when directly visiting the link but blocked via PHP?

Comment: Follow the redirect?  Are you sure the URL you're requesting and the one in the `Location:` header are identical?

Comment: @Brad I'll look into that now.  Any idea from the `MCAPI-PHP` script where I should look to verify that the redirect and `Location:` header are the same?

Comment: Just look at it and tell us... you've X-ed out a lot of the URL.  It's a bug if they're redirecting you from one URL to the same URL, so I suspect you're getting redirected to something else.